# Image doesnt change although the src content changes

Tags: javascript, angular, image

```
<img [(src)]="user.photo_url" alt="profileImage">
```

so i have the src coming from user object and i am changing the image and the user model is updated , but the url remains the same, although the content changes.

**my Update function**

```
this.appService.uploadProfileImage(this.user._id, this.imageFormData).then((response: any) => {
      this.user = response;
    });
```

so 
`the user.photo_url="somr-url"` remains the same , but the image on the path changes.

But its not reflecting on the UI.

So how to reflect the changes on the **img** when the src is updated.

Things i tried but didnt worked.

- Two way binding(as shown)
- ChangeDetectorRef ( detectChange function)

Comment: You can add a `plunkr` or `jsfiddle` to get know better on this

Comment: You have to destroy the image and recreate it to be loaded again from the server. Once the image is downloaded by the browser, there's no need to load it again. Unless the watched variable changes, angular does nothing. How should it know that you did something on the server.

Comment: Is showing an error message in console?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <img src="{{user.photo_url}}" alt="profileImage">
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code, you need to use `[src]` instead of `[(src)]`.

I made a small demo in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zbhdvf?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) & it works just fine!

```
<button (click)="changeImg()">change image source</button>
<br>
<img [src]="img" alt="profileImage">
```

ts code:

```
 state : boolean;
  img: string;

  changeImg() {
    this.state = ! this.state;
    this.img =  this.state ? "https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/blue-sky-with-clouds_1232-936.jpg" : "https://blogs.qub.ac.uk/queensuniversitybelfast/files/2015/05/red-sky.jpg"
  }
```